# Mutex locks and CPU Usage

Tags: c, mutex

```
typedef int lock_variable_type

inline void lock(lock_variable_type *lock_variable)
{ asm volatile (""::: "memory");
  while (*lock_variable);
 *lock_variable = 1;
}

inline void release(lock_variable_type *lock_variable)
{ asm volatile (""::: "memory");
  *lock_variable = 0;
}

inline void init_lock(lock_variable_type *lock_variable)
{ asm volatile (""::: "memory");
  *lock_variable = 0;
}
```

I have this simple rough code for a lock. I know that this code has the potential for a race-condition, but I have a question. If I had multiple threads use the same lock, would it be wasteful of CPU? Or if I had multiple threads multi-tasked on a single CPU, would this sort of code cause any other problems other than the potential race condition?

Comment: Use C11's [`atomic_flag_test_and_set()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag_test_and_set) etc. or pthreads if you want a spin lock instead of a normal mutex.

Answer (score 1):

> If I had multiple threads use the same lock, would it be wasteful of CPU? Or if I had multiple threads multi-tasked on a single CPU, would this sort of code cause any other problems other than the potential race condition?

The worst case here (assuming the race condition is fixed) is that one task acquires the lock, then the OS switches to a different task that tries to acquire the lock but can't (because its already acquired by the first task); causing the second task to waste huge amounts of CPU time for nothing while also preventing the first task from getting the CPU time it needs to release the lock. With more tasks this gets worse (e.g. 99 tasks all wasting CPU time and preventing 1 task from releasing the lock).

Mutexes solve this problem by telling the scheduler not to give a task CPU time until the lock can be acquired; which means that you can't implement a mutex without the operating system's (kernel's) support.

Spinlocks are primarily used in the operating system's kernel where the problem can be solved by disabling the scheduler (and IRQs).

Note that the code you've shown is a spinlock and not a mutex.